# How to fix incomplete multiple image uploads

Tags: laravel

I have problem with uploading multiple images.  The did successfully upload multiple images, but not every image was uploaded.  Here is my form

```
{!! Form::open(['files'=>true,'url'=>'upload/file'])!!}
{!! Form::file('file[]',['multiple'=>'multiple']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('save') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I tried to upload the specific type of images in my validation.

```
public function upload()
{
    $this->validate(request(),['file.*'=>'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png']);
    $files = request()->file('file');
    foreach ($files as $file) {

    $ext  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $file->move(public_path('uploads'),'image_'.time().'.'.$ext);
    }
    return back();
}
```

Sometimes it uploaded multiple images, but not all of the images were uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that:
i can't use time() because i upload these files at the same time
i used

```
Str::random(50)
```

instead

Comment: yes it did use Str::random(40) instead of time method